# How to Use PyEDA to visualize BDDs? Probably very simple

Tags: python, ipython, graphviz, ipython-magic

I'm following the tutorial at http://pyeda.readthedocs.org/en/latest/bdd.html to visualize a majority function BDD. I've done the following :

```
In [1]: %install_ext https://raw.github.com/cjdrake/ipython-magic/master/gvmagic.py

In [2]: %load_ext gvmagic
```

For example, here is the majority function in three variables as a BDD:

```
In [3]: a, b, c = map(bddvar, 'abc')

In [4]: f = a & b | a & c | b & c

In [5]: %dotobj
```

Apparently my graph is now made, but how do I see it? There are no instructions for that on the website

Answer (score 3):

I've only been using PythonEDA for a few hours, so my experience is very limited, but I was having this problem as well. I found a workaround to visualize using the Source module in graphviz. Using the example:

```
>>> from pyeda.inter import *

>>> from graphviz import Source

>>> a, b, c = map(bddvar, 'abc')

>>> f = a & b | a & c | b & c

>>> gv = Source(f.to_dot())

>>> gv.render('render_pdf_name',view=True)
```

will create a pdf in the current working directory, with the name `render_pdf_name`.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

PyEDA author here.

There's an example IPython notebook [here](https://github.com/cjdrake/pyeda/blob/master/ipynb/BDDs.ipynb). It has some examples that might help.